# Cloud 9 want to change directory to my desktop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloud9

Is it possible to cd to my desktop when using the terminal in Cloud 9 for Rails environment?

If not any folder on my local Hard Drive would be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to sync the code in your `cloud9` workspace with your desktop machine.

But you have several ways to copy files **from** and **to** your `cloud9` workspace.

**1. Git/Github**
You can use `git` and `github` (or any other distributed revision control system) to sync your code (i.e. ***Upload*** (`git push`) your code from `cloud9` and later ***download*** (`git clone`) to your desktop machine).

**2. Download from Cloud9**
Rigth-click on the file or folder in the **Workspace tree** (on the left of your `cloud9` workspace) and select `Download`.

**3. Upload from your local machine**
Drag-and-drop you local file to a specific folder on your **Workspace tree**.