# cloud9 IDE loading data from excel

Tags: mysql, excel, cloud9-ide

How would I load data from xlsx (local copy) into cloud9 IDE mysql - ? How would I set the path for the local hard drive, and what else would I need to do ?

Comment: If I understand your question, you want to move your xlsx file from your local machine to your cloud9 IDE, this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43597117/6780663) answers that.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud9 cannot use local files. The only way this would work is if you were using a Linux machine that Cloud9 is connected to as an SSH workspace.

You can upload the file to the host by using File > Upload Local Files... . This will create a copy on the cloud host that can be used by your code.